# JNDI tomcat to weblogic

Tags: tomcat, weblogic, jndi, weblogic12c

If JNDI prefix is "java:/comp/Resources" for Tomcat 7, what should it be for weblogic 12c?

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
java:/comp/env/...
```